# Performance issue with Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I click Modules in Admin Panel Back Office, it is taking arround 2mins to view the modules page. I want to know how to find where is the problem.

I have seen the below link for performance issue, but even after emptying the guest table it is taking same time(2mins).

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/266421-500000-rows-on-ps-guest-sounds-too-big/

Kindly suggest to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: My back office was also very slow. Presta support asked me to upgrade my prestashop to latest version. I just did it and it is faster now. But i must say when i upgraded, if i turn error reporting on. I get few warnings. They not interfere with the back office or front office but they are still there.

Comment: Is browser's console showing errors?

Answer (score 0):

Go to file defines.inc.php and value change:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

for:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

with this active developer mode and you see error in php and server...

Answer (score 0):

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);
```

This will show you all hooks and controller executions time with a lot of details, you could probably find where you have a bottleneck with only that.

[image]